# port blocking for multiple user requests

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I have a question that nobody seems to help with. How will this be handled in a production mode with thousands of requests at the same time?

I did a simple test case:

```
module.exports = {
    index: function (req, res){
        if (req.param('foo') == 'bar'){
            async.series([
                function(callback){
                    for (k=0; k <= 50000; k++){
                        console.log('did something stupid a few times');
                    }

                    callback();
                }
            ], function(){
                return res.json(null);
            });


        }else{
            return res.view('homepage', {

            });
        }

    }
};
```

Now if I go to http://localhost:1337/?foo=bar it will obviously wait a while before it responds. So if I now open a different session (other browser or incognito, and go to http://localhost:1337/ I am expecting a result immediately. Instead it is waiting for the other request to finish and only then it will let this request go through.

Therefore it is not asynchronous and it is a huge problem if I have as much as 2 ppl at the same time operating this app. I mean this app will have drop downs coming from databases, html files being served etc...

My question is this: how does one handle such an issue??? I hear the word "promises vs callbacks" - is this some sort of a solution to this?

I know about clustering, but that only separates the requests over the amount of cpu's, ultimately you will fix it by at most allowing 8 people at the same time without being blocked. It won;t handle 100 requests at the same time...

P.S. That test was to simplify the example, but think of someone uploading a file, a web service that goes to a different server, a point of sales payment terminal waiting for a user to input the pin, someone downloading a file from the app, etc...

Answer (score 0):

nodejs is event driven and runs your Javascript as single threaded.  So, as long as your code from the first request is sitting in that `for` loop, nodejs can't do anything else and won't get to the next event in the event queue so thus your second request has to wait for the first one to finish.

Now, if you used a true async operation such as `setTimeout()` instead of your big `for` loop, then nodejs could service other events while the first request was waiting for the `setTimeout()`.

The general rule in nodejs is to avoid doing anything that takes a ton of CPU in your main nodejs app.  If you are stuck with something CPU-intensive, then you're best to either run clusters (as many as CPUs you have) or move the CPU-intensive work to some sort of worker queue that is served by different processes and let the OS time slice those other processes while the main nodejs process stays free and ready to service new incoming requests.

> My question is this: how does one handle such an issue??? I hear the word "promises vs callbacks" - is this some sort of a solution to this?
>
> I know about clustering, but that only separates the requests over the amount of cpu's, ultimately you will fix it by at most allowing 8 people at the same time without being blocked. It won;t handle 100 requests at the same time...

Most of the time, a server process spends most of the time of a request doing things that are asynchronous in nodejs (reading files, talking to other servers, doing database operations, etc...) where the actual work is done outside the nodejs process.  When that is the case, nodejs does not block and is free to work on other requests while the async operations from other requests are underway.  The little bit of CPU time coordinating these operations can be helped further by clustering though it's probably worth testing a single process first to see if clustering is really needed.

> P.S. That test was to simplify the example, but think of someone uploading a file, a web service that goes to a different server, a point of sales payment terminal waiting for a user to input the pin, someone downloading a file from the app, etc...

All the operations you mentioned here can be done truly asynchronously so they won't block your nodejs app like your `for` loop does so basically the `for` loop isn't a good simulation of any of this.  You need to use a real async operation to simulate it.  Real async operations do their work outside of the main nodejs thread and then just post an event to the event queue when they are done, allowing nodejs to do other things while the async operations are doing their work.  That's the key.

Comment: Hi - Get what you are saying, however I have seen the same issue with a request to pull lots of data from a database: which basically replaces the for loop. Basically, you have to wait for the list of records to be pulled form the database and then during which time, the other requests are blocked.

Comment: @MihaiPop - That depends entirely upon the capabilities of your database and on how much you're sending back.  Certainly, if you're loading up your database, then it may not be able to handle multiple concurrent requests itself.  This is an overall system issue (not only node.js) and the weakest link will control the max throughput you can have.  If all node.js is doing is grabbing data from a database and sending it out over a socket, I rather doubt that node.js is the bottleneck.  You'd have to profile to understand where the bottleneck is and what to change to get more throughput.

Comment: @MihaiPop - I don't know what you want from me here.  I've described how things work and you seem to just want to argue with me.  node.js is extremely scalable when used properly, but it must be used properly in order to achieve those advantages.  And, if there are other components in the system (such as databases, other servers, etc...), then system scalability is a system issue, not just a node.js issue and requires both careful design, but also testing and possibly design modifications to maximize scale.

Comment: Wow - there is no "argument" here! The point is that you like everyone else give a GENERAL advice, which is: "design this carefully"! But who can tell me how to make this work without blocking a port? I mean before I submitted my question - I have tested numerous ways of approach. My current one is submitting and releasing the request with a response containing a unique reference for the request which then gets placed in a delayed ajax function response, while in the background the application continues and then when done, it will send the response via sockets with the refrence! Do you SEEE???

Comment: All tutorials on nodejs handle a request and a response - they are all website tutorials - but put 2 ppl at the same time and suddenly you have an issue: all request regarding database is handling inputs, pulling records out, formatting these records and outputting to the screen. Think of a simple form with 2 comboxes which lists types of tasks and person titles Each come from the node. The one has to wait for the OTHER to finish - HOW do you code that? The one requests waits for the other. That is my question: it is not an argument - it is a question. Because that answer does not exist.

Comment: Okay a bit more info. I went the route of getting the request, responding with a unique reference, then I submitted the data to a second server on a different port via request.post, then that one handles the actual process and responds via sockets. Same issue - BLOCKING! Do you understand that I am not here to argue - I am trying to ask for help and if you can;t help then say so, but from what I am writting you can SEE that I am trying everything under the sun and I am open to any suggestions - except the advise: "code properly"... I mean that is super not-helpful!

Comment: I've explained (and I think you understand) this is a system issue that can only be addressed by understanding your specific system - yet your question provides no detailed description of your system and no real code.  There is no generic answer that would be specific enough to solve anyone's problems.

Comment: If you want two simultaneous requests to be processed truly in parallel even when there's lots of CPU work and database work to be done, then you need to make sure every single component of your system can use multiple threads or processes and actually will use them in the cases you care about most.  For node.js, that means it must be clustered and for every other part of your system (such as a database) you need to select or configure a component that can also run truly parallel operations.

Comment: If you want advice about the test you set up where you saw blocking, then you'd have to post all the code involved in that test for us to see what exactly you were doing there.

Comment: Hi thank you. I added a gist here: https://gist.github.com/mihaip007/b1c345643b6e8ab779cd6b02eecec64a

Comment: I am using Sails. This is a very basic test, but here is what I did in a controller which handles a request like: "http://myapp/dostuff".

Comment: So basically when a request to "dostuff" happens, then I simply respond with a reference which will then be kept in an object on the client side.

I was expecting that once there was a response, nodejs would release the port. It does! But I then pass the request to a second sails app on a different port using the request.post to pass the data to the controllers "socket_listen".

Comment: It does work and it passes the data, where some crazy big blocking operation would then occur )in this case reading a huge file). Upon completion, that server would then pass the result to the client via a socket, which will then cause on the client side to trigger a callback function using that reference passed in the first place.

At THAT moment, one call is supposed to not be blocked by the more involved call, but it does.